# how many countries have organised more than one edition of olympic games? using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

let's say: there is a data frame:

```
country       edition  sports    Athletes               Medals
india          1990    Aquatics  HAJOS, Alfred          gold
india          1990    Aquatics  HERSCHMANN, Otto       silver
india          1990    Aquatics  DRIVAS, Dimitrios      silver
US             2008    Athletics MALOKINIS, Ioannis     silver
US             2009    Athletics CHASAPIS, Spiridon      gold
france         2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios   gold
france         2010    golf      HAJOS, Alfred           silver
france         2011    golf      ANDREOU, Joannis        silver
```

answer should be 2

Comment: That data doesn't make much sense without any context, and your question is unclear.

Comment: we are her to provide you with help if you are stuck and not to solve your homework. Try yourself and if you are stuck you can ask.

Comment: @peeps You can do this `(df.groupby('country').size()>1).sum()`

Comment: @moys by doing this, you are finding the frequency of countries and then summing it. my question is not this! my question is find the countries who have hosted the Olympics more than once? in my question, the US and France have hosted 2 times so the answer should be the US and France. so the count should be 2 bcoz two countries have hosted the Olympics.

Comment: @peeps did you run the code? you can try update your dataframe to have one of country 3 times(example US) & then run this. You will still get the answer as 2. Try it.

Comment: @moys let's say india has 3 records in the same year 1990. After running your logic the output will be india=3,US =2,France=2 ...so the count after taking the sum() will be 3...but india hosted only one time.

Comment: @peeps You did not mention that there can be multiple records with same values. Update you dataframe in the question to cover all your scenarios & then we can look into it.

Comment: @moys updated my question! please look into it

Comment: [Provides some background from solving](https://data36.com/pandas-tutorial-2-aggregation-and-grouping/)

Comment: @moys if i want to find out which edition distributed most silver medals what i should do ?  i am trying df.groupby('Edition')[df['Medals=='Silver']].count().idxmax() its giving me error.

Comment: @peeps Please post another question. I am sure the community here can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the 2 alternatives below.

```
df.groupby('country')['edition'].nunique().gt(1).sum()
```

or

```
(df.groupby('country')['edition'].nunique()>(1)).sum()
```

Comment: thanxs a lot for help.